# Why is my update query not accepting union subquery as the column value expression?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to make this query work.
Account table has 1:N relation to many User table rows.
Account table also has a column referencing User table called `admin_id`.
I am trying to make sure that all accounts with admin_id=null is updated with the correct main admin. That is the only owner if there is any (there can be at most one), otherwise the admin with lowest id (first created). Deleted users have column `deletedAt` not null and these users are never to be considered. If a user is admin or owner is denoted by the `role` column of the User table (there are other roles as well, but those we dont want assigned to admin_id). If there is no owner nor admin, admin_id column should remain null.

```
UPDATE Account c
SET c.admin_id = (
  (
      SELECT u.id AS id
      FROM User u
      WHERE u.account_id = Account.id
      AND u.role IN ("admin", "owner")
      AND u.deletedAt IS NULL
      ORDER BY u.role DESC, u.id ASC
      LIMIT 1
  ) # << here mysql workbench reports missing parenthesis
  UNION
  (
    SELECT NULL AS id
  )
  LIMIT 1
)
WHERE c.admin_id IS NULL
```

However mysql workbench is reporting missing parenthesis before `UNION` keyword. And db server also responds with syntax error.
But when I copy out the entire union from the assignment (leaving out the reference to Account table) and run it, it returns what I want.

Any idea what's wrong?

Suggestions to do the same in a different way are also welcome...

Using 10.2.31-MariaDB-1:10.2.31+maria~bionic

Comment: `(SELECT .. LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT NULL) LIMIT 1` is free to give you the one row from either of the `SELECTs`.  This may not be what you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if your current update logic be correct, but the union which brings in a `NULL` value is superfluous, because should the first subquery fail to find anything, it would return `NULL` by default already.  So, you may simply write:

```
UPDATE Account c
SET admin_id = (
    SELECT u.id AS id
    FROM User u
    WHERE u.account_id = c.id          AND
          u.role IN ('admin', 'owner') AND
          u.deletedAt IS NULL
    ORDER BY u.role DESC, u.id
    LIMIT 1
)
WHERE admin_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like you're right. I was convinced it is going to be error if there are no such users and so I didn't even try :/ My bad. I'm still curious why the union is a problem though...